# pg_dump windows command prompt invalid command

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

trying to using pg_dump to backup a postgres db

i connected through the command prompt and here is my command following this tutorial http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-backup-database/

```
pg_dump -U postgres -W -F t lucz_2017 > X:\postgres_backup\lucz_backup.tar
```

it gives me an error

```
Invalid command \postgres_backup. Try \? for help.
```

what am I doing wrong?

the db name and paths are correct

windows 7 running this from the CMD

Comment: Which OS are you on and from where are you running this command?

Comment: Try putting your directory location in single quotes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are running pg_dump from psql. Get out of psql and run pg_dump command from Windows Command prompt.  pg_dump is its own executable, different from psql.

Comment: im not running it from psql...? i never call psql in my command. I call pg_dump

Comment: The error message `Invalid command \postgres_backup. Try \? for help.
` is generated by psql, so you are in it somehow.  Can you open a brand new cmd.exe and run the pg_dump command from there?

Comment: ahh you were right I was already in psql trying to execute this command!

Comment: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin>pg_dump -U postgres -F t lucz_2017 > X:\postgres_backup\lucz.tar

Answer (score 10):

This works for me in Windows PowerShell in Windows 10:

```
.\pg_dump.exe --username "yourUserName" --no-owner "yourDatabasName" >./filename.sql
```

Comment: Only if the path is loaded, in my case I just linked directly to it:

'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\pg_dump.exe'

Answer (score 1):

**DB Backup**

For windows user, You can follow the procedure below,

**Run cmd as Admimistrator**

Go to pg bin directory using

**cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<VERSION_NUMBER>\bin**

Type any of the following 3 commands, all of these commands will give same result.

```
1. .\pg_dump.exe -Fc -U Username DB_Name > backup_dump.dump
2. .\pg_dump.exe --format=c -U Username -p 5432 DB_Name  > backup_dump.dump
3. .\pg_dump.exe -Fc "host=localhost port=5432  dbname=dbname user=postgres password=***" > mydb_export.backup
```

**DB Restore:**

```
pg_restore -v -U postgres -d backup < backup_dump.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

To backup my "DVD_RENTAL_DB" database to a local folder on my computer I had to use the below in the Windows command prompt while running it as an administrator:

Don't use shell redirection (>) on Windows with pg_dump. The shell will helpfully "correct" encoding issues and corrupt your dump.
Instead, specify the output filename with the -f option (enter your respective information):

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_dump" -U postgres -p 5432 -W -F p -h localhost -f C:\Postgres_DB_Backups\DVD_RENTAL_DB.sql DVD_RENTAL_DB
```

This worked for me ONLY after I put double quotes around the pg_dump executable file path, before when I was adding the file path without double quotes the back up was not working; probably due to spaces in my file path. The PostgreSQL documentation didn't mention anything about double quotes around the pg_dump executable file path.

To Restore my Database I used the following in the Windows command prompt while running it as an administrator:

1. Open the Windows Command Prompt as an Administrator and you should be in this directory:

```
C:\Windows\System32>
```

2. Then type the following:

```
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\
```

3. Then you'll be here in this directory:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin>
```

4. Type the following (enter your respective information):

```
psql -U postgres -d DVD_RENTAL_DB -f C:\Postgres_DB_Backups\DVD_RENTAL_DB.sql
```

5. You'll be prompted for your password, then your database will be restored.

Answer (score -1):

**Steps to using pg_dump on windows**

1. Access cmd as Admin and type
2. cd path_to_pg_dump PRESS ENTER
3. pg_dump --username your_user_name
   --table=table_name --data-only --column-inserts your_database > my_table_data.sql
   PRESS ENTER